# Angular Code not executing

Tags: angularjs

I am taking baby steps in learning AngularJS to act as a front end with my Python/Django projects. I just wrote a simple AngularJS page as below.

The expected output of the code is **Joe is 35 years old.**

while the actual output of the code is **{{ person.name }} is {{ person.age }} years old.**

The code is as below.

```html
<html>

<body ng-app="scrumboard.demo">
  <div ng-controller="ScrumboardController">
    <p>{{ person.name }} is {{ person.age }} years old.</p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('scrumboard.demo', [])
          .controller('ScrumboardController', ['$scope', ScrumboardController]);

        function ScrumboardController($scope) {
          $scope.person = {
            name = 'Joe',
            age = 35
          };
        }());
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **`object` declaration** is wrong,

```
$scope.person = {
   name = 'Joe',
   age = 35
};
```

`name = 'Joe',` should be `name: 'Joe',` and `age = 35` should be `age: 35`

so,

```
$scope.person = {
   name: 'Joe',
   age: 35
};
```

```html
<html>

<body ng-app="scrumboard.demo">
  <div ng-controller="ScrumboardController">
    <p>{{ person.name }} is {{ person.age }} years old.</p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('scrumboard.demo', [])
          .controller('ScrumboardController', ['$scope', ScrumboardController]);

        function ScrumboardController($scope) {
          $scope.person = {
            name: 'Joe',
            age: 35
          };
        }
     }());
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$scope.person = {
        name = 'Joe',
        age = 35
      };
```

to

```
$scope.person = {
        name: 'Joe',
        age: 35
      };
```

```html
<html>

<body ng-app="scrumboard.demo">
  <div ng-controller="ScrumboardController">
    <p>{{ person.name }} is {{ person.age }} years old.</p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('scrumboard.demo', [])
          .controller('ScrumboardController', ['$scope', ScrumboardController]);

        function ScrumboardController($scope) {
          $scope.person = {
            name: 'Joe',
            age: 35
          };
        }
     }());
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't self-invoking anonymous function end with `})();`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sravan and Jag. Asa rightly pointed out the problem was with the object notation which I fixed by changing

```
name = 'Joe',
age = 35
```

to
    name: 'Joe',
    age: 35

However after doing that the code still didn't work. SO after further scrutiny I found out I had missed one curly bracket '}' here

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('scrumboard.demo', [])
      .controller('ScrumboardController', ['$scope', ScrumboardController]);

    function ScrumboardController($scope) {
      $scope.person = {
        name = 'Joe',
        age = 35
      };
    }());
```

Which I changed to this

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('scrumboard.demo', [])
      .controller('ScrumboardController', ['$scope', ScrumboardController]);

    function ScrumboardController($scope) {
      $scope.person = {
        name = 'Joe',
        age = 35
      };
      }
    }());
```

and it worked.